# Cron configuration on Mavericks

Tags: macos, cron

How can I configure cron to send a local email only to the crontab owner with the cron job output.

This worked with Lion, could check the cron emails by just running mail in the terminal so I don't know what changed or how to reimplement that behavior.

Comment: `/usr/bin/mail` will send actual mail over the internet from the command line to real mail addresses. Would that be OK or do you need it to only send mail to an account on the local host?

Comment: I only want it sent to the account on the localhost

Answer (score 1):

This should be working and is certainly working on my Mavericks box.

If you don't have a "MAILTO" line in the crontab then output should get sent to the owner of the crontab.

Are you sure the job actually outputs something? Have you tried putting a job in the crontab that will be sure to have some output such as

```
*/10 * * * * *  /bin/echo "Working fine"
```

Are you sure you don't have a `.forward` file in the user home directory?

Have you tried using `sendmail` to send some mail to the account and see if it gets through.

Comment: What does `*/10` do?

Comment: The "*/10" runs the command every ten minutes. `man -s 5 crontab` at the command line will get you a good manual of the format.